# Checkpoint Hyper-V with Android

Tags: hyper-v, visual-studio-emulator

I'am able to create checkpoints with Hyper-V for my Android VM, but even if I apply an old checkpoint in the Hyper-V, the Visual Studio Emulator for Android does not take account of the checkpoint.

**How to force Visual Studio Emulator for Android to apply a checkpoint?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to launch the emulator via command line.

Here is the normal commande line with the original image.vdh

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe" /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Tablet\image_7E226D05-2103-4581-94FC-4341DD51BFD4.avhd" /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet.*"
```

Here is the command line with the checkpoint:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe" /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 10.1\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet" /memSize 2048 /diagonalSize 10.1 /video "2560x1600" /vhd "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\10.1_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Tablet\image_7E226D05-2103-4581-94FC-4341DD51BFD4.avhd" /name "VS Emulator 10.1-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Tablet.*"
```

You just have to call the right image in the /vdh argument.